# Let $X$ be a random variable with Cauchy distribution, compute the density function of $Y=\frac{1}{1+X^2}$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, density-function

> Let $X$ be a random variable with Cauchy distribution, if $$Y=\frac{1}{1+X^2}$$ then compute the density function of $Y$

I have tried to use some random variable transformation theorem using the functions $\frac{1}{1+X}$ and $X^2$ but I have not been able to get very far, any suggestion or help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3099373/321264

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem can also be solved via the change of the variable in PDF.
$$X:\,f(x)=\frac{1}{\pi}\frac{1}{1+x^2}; \,\,Y=\frac{1}{1+X^2}; \,\,y=f(x);\,\,g(y)-?$$
$$1+x^2=\frac{1}{f(x)}\,\Rightarrow x=\sqrt{\frac{1-f(x)}{f(x)}}$$
$$ dx=-\frac{1}{2}\bigg(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-f(x)}\sqrt f(x)}+\frac{\sqrt{1-f(x)}}{(\sqrt f(x))^3}\bigg)df=-\frac{1}{2}\frac{df}{\sqrt{f(x)}\sqrt{1-f(x)}f(x)}$$
Therefore, after changing the variable, the PDF looks ($y=f(x)$)
$$\frac{dx}{\pi}\frac{1}{1+x^2}=-\frac{1}{2\pi}\frac{f(x)\,df}{\sqrt{f(x)}\sqrt{1-f(x)}f(x)}=-\frac{1}{2\pi}\frac{dy}{\sqrt{y}\sqrt{1-y}}$$
We also have to note that $y>0$ at any $x$, and $y\in(1;0)$ for $x\in(0;\infty)$; taking the usual order of integration (from $0$ to$1$) and multiplying PDF by $2$ (taking into consideration the part of $x\in(-\infty;0)\,$), we get $$g(y)=\frac{1}{\pi}\frac{1}{\sqrt{y}\sqrt{1-y}}$$
$$\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^1\frac{dy}{\sqrt{y}\sqrt{1-y}}=\frac{1}{\pi}B\Big(\frac{1}{2};\frac{1}{2}\Big)=1$$

Answer (score 2):

$$P(Y \leq y)=P(X^{2} \geq \frac  1y -1)$$ $$=2P(X \geq \sqrt {\frac 1 y -1})$$ $$=2\int_{\sqrt {\frac 1 y -1}}^{\infty} \frac 1 {\pi} \frac 1 {1+t^{2}} dt.$$ Now just differentiate w.r.t. $y$.

Comment: I have a question: si correct
$$2P(X \geq \sqrt{\frac{1}{y}-1})=2(1-P\left(X<\sqrt{\frac{1}{y}-1}\right)$$

Comment: @NickWeber Yes. $P(X<t)=\int_{-\infty} ^{t} f_X(x)dx$ and $P(X>t)=\int_t^{\infty} f_X(x)dx$ so there is no need to write $P(X>t)$ as $1-P(x<t)$.

Comment: One question more: Why
$$P(Y \leq y)=P(X^{2} \geq \frac  1y -1)$$ $$=2P(X \geq \sqrt {\frac 1 y -1})$$ i don't understand the second equality

Comment: I think that comes from the fact that  $X^2 \geq \frac{1}{y} -1 \Rightarrow X\geq +\sqrt{\frac{1}{y}-1} $ or $X\geq -\sqrt{\frac{1}{y}-1} $ 
And then occupying the additivity property of measure and symmetry you get but I am not sure

Comment: It follows from symmetry of Cauchy distribution. @NickWeber